# Method Replacement with Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My project uses Spring Boot (& MVC) and I have to replace a method code dynamically at runtime.

I have looked at "MethodReplacer Interface" API from below link:

[http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/MethodReplacer.html](http://I%20have%20to%20replace%20a%20method%20dynamically%20at%20runtime%20in%20my%20project%20(which%20uses%20Spring%20Boot%20&%20Spring%20MVC).%20%20I%20have%20looked%20at%20%22MethodReplacer%20Interface%22%20API%20from%20below%20link:%20http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/MethodReplacer.html%20%20Could%20you%20please%20help%20me%20with%20an%20example%20using%20Annotations%20to%20replace%20a%20method%20code%20?)

I could not find any example which uses method replacement using Annotations.

Could you please help me with **an example using Annotations** which replaces a method code at Runtime ?

Comment: what about [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/MethodReplacementExample.htm) example?

Comment: Bilak: That example does not use Annotations.

Comment: I don't know about any spring's annotation that is handling this. If you want some annotation you can probably create your own and create some processor. Other way to replace the method can be using AOP (acpects).

Comment: Maybe you can look at [this project](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix) it's android, but you can get an idea how to process method replacement.